# Powerpoint change shape outline/fill color with animation

Tags: ms-office, powerpoint

My Powerpoint presentation contains some shapes (arrows and circles) and i'd like to use animations to change their outline and fill colors. The problem i am facing is that i want to change the colors multiple times, but each time i insert a new animation it overrides my old ones for this shape. I feel like the solution should be trivial, but i just can't get it done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. create multiple shapes with different outline and colors: let's say you want a box to go from empty and black to filled white. Create two boxes, one empty and black, the second filled white.
2. set the animation so that the first disappears while the next appears. To add more animations to the same object, use the add animation to prevent overriding of animations [image]

Comment: clever idea, but this runs into the same problem, that the disapear animation overrides the preexisting appear animation :-( I would need rectange 3 to appear first, then disappear and be replaced by rectangle 3 in your example

Comment: check the edited answer. As you can see from the image, it is doable.

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me find my mistake. I never pressed Add Animation and just used the left bar, so all i did was changing the previous animation :-)